# Как запустить приложение, написанное на Qt C++, на другом ПК, где Qt нету?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtcreator

У меня на моем ПК, все запускается без ошибок. В папку с .exe я положил все нужные библиотеки. Но на другом ПК пишет, что Qt плагин не найден.
[image: Вот скриншот:]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ищите в каталоге установки Qt папку plugins\platforms
2. Копируете из нее qwindows.dll в папку platforms, созданную в каталоге с вашим exe-шником

Comment: ну вот к примеру если вы рисуете jpeg и забудете соответствующий plugin скопировать, то никаких ошибок не будет, кроме как пустые места вместо картинок

Comment: Может и такое быть. Но в данном случае, раз приложение вовсе отказывается стартовать, ему не хватает именно qwindows.dll

Comment: для windows да, это распространённая ошибка, причём часто не читая руководства народ кладёт её вместе с exe

Answer (score 11):

Вам нужно:

- собрать релиз
- использовать программу [windeployqt](https://habr.com/ru/post/262211/)
  [image: скрин windeployqt]
  Ее нужно запустить из папки, где лежит .exe вашей программы.

Comment: У меня не запускается windeployqt. Тоесть запускается, но только на мгновенье, а потом сразу же закрывается

Comment: @RomanKhvalko - а как вы его запускаете?

Comment: С папки, где лежит .exe. Просто запустил и все.

Comment: А теперь пришло время прочитать пост на Хабре(на который я ссылаюсь). Эта программа - утилита с интерфейсом командной строки. Ее и запускать надо из командной строки.

Answer (score 5):

А если сделать без специализированного ПО, то можно так:

Во-первых [вот тут](http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015) есть великолепная инструкция, которой всегда пользуюсь.

Во-вторых, если своими словами, как-то так:

1. В версии сборки ставите Release
2. Собираете приложение
3. Копируете Ваш `.exe`-файл в другое расположение
4. Запускаете
5. Вылазит ошибка о том, что не хватает определённой `.dll`-библиотеки
6. Ищете нужную виндовым поиском по файлам и подставляете в ту папку, куда Вы скопировали `.exe`
7. Если вылазит ошибка не связанная с наличием какой-либо библиотеки, копируете все библиотеки из папки с библиотеками Qt (название начинается с `Q` и расширение `.dll`) в папку с Вашим проектом, а потом удаляете лишние. Долго, но действенно
8. Когда Ваше приложение, наконец, запустилось и все лишние библиотеки удалены, то, что осталось копируете на любой другой комп без Qt и запускаете.

Comment: windeployqt - это утилита из состава Qt под Windows.

Comment: @gbg Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @gbg Я полагаю, работает она только для Windows? Или для Unix-подобных тоже аналог есть?

Comment: для мака точно был macdeployqt, может и для linux есть, но не смотрел. А вот c windeployqt у меня так до конца и не получилось подружиться, он мне не добавлял qml-библиотеки. В целом было ощущение (каюсь, подробно не копал) что он подцепил только то что безусловно линкуется на старте приложения и без чего оно даже не встает, а всякие qml-компоненты линкуются уже потом и как плагины, так что приложение успешно запускается, но дальше их не находит и завершается с ошибкой

Comment: @V-Mor Для Unix-подобных не надо "таскать с собой" Qt. При сборке пакета, указываются зависимости от нужных компонентов, а штатный пакетный менеджер их поставит. Или удостоверится, что они уже есть в системе.